# Debian install without internet

Tags: debian, sqlite, mono-framework

My aim is to install debian  with mono, xsp2 and sqlite without using internet. 
First I made the 3 debian DVDs and Downloaded manually the packages of mono, sqlite and xsp2, after Checking the dependenciesn,  I noticed that libmono-posix2.0-cil_2.10.8.1-8  depends on libmono-system2.0-cil and this last depends also on libmono-posix2.0-cil_2.10.8.1-8 
Please have a look on the following dependencies:

libmono-posix2.0-cil_2.10.8.1-8
        Depends: 
            libc6 (>= 2.13) | libc6.1 (>= 2.13) | libc0.1 (>= 2.13), 
            libmono-corlib2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3), 
            libmono-system2.0-cil (>= 2.10.3), 
            mono-runtime (>= 2.10.1)
        Replaces: libmono2.0-cil (<< 2.0)

libmono-system2.0-cil_2.10.8.1-8
        Depends: 
                libc6 (>= 2.13) | libc6.1 (>= 2.13) | libc0.1 (>= 2.13), 
                libmono-corlib2.0-cil (>= 2.6.3), 
                libmono-posix2.0-cil (>= 2.4), 
                libmono-security2.0-cil (>= 2.6.7), 
                mono-runtime (>= 2.10.8.1), mono-runtime (<< 2.10.8.2)
        Suggests: 
                libasound2 (>> 1.0.18), 
                libcups2 (>= 1.3.8), 
                libgamin0, libgdiplus (>= 2.6.7), 
                libmono-winforms2.0-cil (>= 2.4), 
                libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1)
        Replaces: 
                mono-classlib-2.0 (<< 1.1.13.6), 
                mono-classlib-2.0-dbg (<< 1.1.13.6)

Can advise for the best way to install debian without internet

Comment: Seriously, why don't you just try it? If you have the set of dvds and then just don't add any remote apt sources then you should have all the debian packages already

Comment: I agree with you, but mono xsp2 are not delivred with debian

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with those dependencies, despite them being circular. Simplifying the names... posix-2.10.8 relies system-2.10.3 or higher, and system-2.10.8 relies on posix-2.4 or higher, so version 2.10.8 of both packages means they both satisfies the other's requirements.

PS: In case this is the source of your confusion... 2.10 is a higher version than 2.4